# Excel 2010 - look for all the cells in an array with a specified value in and list all the cells in one column of the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I search for specific content in an array, and list the content of a specific column in the same row?
I'm looking at a project monitoring spreadsheet which records completion dates for each item across a fleet of machines.  I need to identify the machine numbers (in column A) which are incomplete and how many elements are left to complete.  I've set it up to count the blanks in another column, and I want to list the machine numbers according to the number of blanks.

Comment: please add some example data with desired output, it's very difficult to understand your question now.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already counted the blanks, just sort by descending values on that column. If you can't do this for whatever reason, then please edit your question to be more clear. If you do so, then I'll revise my answer based on the new information.

[image]